# How To select one data from many data (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have Query

> `SELECT * FROM PPI_CD WHERE PATIENT_NO = 14683`

Results from this query display some of the same data based on PATIENT_NO

[image]

How to order only the latest data out? only One

Full Query

```
SELECT
    PPI_ID,
    co.order_no,
    p.RM_NO,
    co.patient_name,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.DOB) as Age,
    p.sex,
    co.order_date as TGL_MASUK,
    NVL(il.NAME, '0') as ICD,
    NVL(ppi.HPA_UC, '0') AS UC,
    NVL(ppi.HPA_IVL, '0') AS IVL,
    NVL(ppi.HPA_CVL, '0') AS CVL,
    NVL(ppi.HPA_ETT, '0') AS ETT,
    NVL(ppi.IRS_VAP, '0') AS VAP,
    NVL(ppi.IRS_PLEB, '0') AS PLEB,
    NVL(ppi.IRS_ISK, '0') AS ISK,
    NVL(ppi.IRS_IAD, '0') AS IAD,
    NVL(ppi.TB, '0') AS TB,
    NVL(ppi.HK, '0') AS HK,
    NVL(ppi.AB, '0') AS AB,
    NVL(ppi.ANTIBIOTIK , '0') AS ANTIBIOTIK,
    NVL(ppi.DEKU, '0') AS DEKU,
    NVL(ppi.JK_DARAH , '0') AS DARAH,
    NVL(ppi.JK_SWAB , '0') AS SWAB,
    NVL(ppi.JK_SPUTUM , '0') AS SPUTUM,
    NVL(ppi.JK_URINE , '0') AS URINE,
    NVL(ppi.TEMP, 'N/A') AS TEMP
FROM case_orders co
LEFT JOIN PPI_CD cd
ON cd.patient_no = co.patient_no
LEFT JOIN illness_lists il
ON il.illness_no = cd.illness_no
LEFT JOIN patients p
ON p.contact_no = co.patient_no
LEFT JOIN PPI ppi
ON ppi.RM_NO = p.RM_NO
WHERE CO.status_no=5
ORDER BY CO.ORDER_DATE ASC;
```

the problem is with this
[image]
out 2 data which should be only one data

Comment: How do you define latest?

Answer (score 0):

For just one patient, you can order by and a row limiting clause:

```
select *
from ppi_cd
where patient_no = 14683
order by posted_date desc
fetch first row only
```

If you want the latest record per `patient_no`, you can do:

```
select c.*
from ppi_cd c
where c.posted_date = (
    select max(c1.posted_date) from ppi_cd c1 where c1.patient_no = c.patient_no
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select pc.*
from (select pc.*, row_number() over (partition by PATIENT_NO order by pc.post_date DESC) as seq
      from PPI_CD pc
     ) pc
where pc.seq = 1;
```